# Kafka Streams App - count and sum aggregate

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to create a KTable from a KGroupedStream to store the sum of the value for each key.

```
 final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
 final KTable<String, Long> sum = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
            .groupByKey()
            .aggregate(new Initializer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply() {
                    return Long.MIN_VALUE;
                }
            }, new Aggregator<String, Long, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(final String key, final Long value,final Long aggregate) {
                    aggregate += value;
                    return aggregate;
                }
            }, Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Byte, byte[]>>as("counts-store"));
```

but am getting the error:

```
The method aggregate(Initializer<VR>, Aggregator<? super Object,? super Object,VR>, Materialized<Object,VR,KeyValueStore<Bytes,byte[]>>) in the type KGroupedStream<Object,Object> is not applicable for the arguments (new Initializer<Long>(){}, new Aggregator<String,Long,Long>(){}, Materialized<String,Long,KeyValueStore<Byte,byte[]>>)
```

All the examples I've seen pass in a Serde as the third argument but I have tried this and get a very similar error (I think this might be from an older version as it does not match with the signature of the current implementation?):

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    final KTable<String, Long> sum = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
            .groupByKey()
            .aggregate(new Initializer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply() {
                    return Long.MIN_VALUE;
                }
            }, new Aggregator<String, Long, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(final String key, final Long value,final Long aggregate) {
                    aggregate += value;
                    return aggregate;
                }
            }, Serdes.Long());
```

Error:

```
The method aggregate(Initializer<VR>, Aggregator<? super Object,? super Object,VR>, Materialized<Object,VR,KeyValueStore<Bytes,byte[]>>) in the type KGroupedStream<Object,Object> is not applicable for the arguments (new Initializer<Long>(){}, new Aggregator<String,Long,Long>(){}, Serde<Long>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Using Kafka version: 2.1.0

Comment: Side remark: to compute the sum, you initial value should be zero, not `Long.MIN_VALUE` to compute the correct result. Similar for count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

1. For `Materialized.as` instead `java.lang.Byte` you should pass `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes`
2. You shouldn't modify `final` variable: `aggregate += value;`
3. You have to add types of key and value to `StreamsBuilder::stream` call (`builder.<String, Long>stream("streams-plaintext-input")`)

After modification it should looks more or less as follow:

```java
KTable<String, Long> sum = builder.<String, Long>stream("streams-plaintext-input")
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(new Initializer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long apply() {
                return Long.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }, new Aggregator<String, Long, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long apply(final String key, final Long value,final Long aggregate) {
                return aggregate + value;
            }
        }, Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("counts-store"));
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. 3 was the root cause, it's so obvious now!. 1 I was already doing (not clear from the snippet). 2 showed up after I fixed 3. Thanks again